# Isotope plugin corner stamp issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I'm building a project using Dave Desandro's totally kick-ass Isotope plugin, and so far, everything has been going great. However, in the right corner of my page, I'd like to use the corner stamp feature to keep a specific  there at all times.

The corner stamp appears, but the other elements do not seem to acknowledge it. Any thoughts on this? The Isotope portion of the jQuery can be seen below, and the full test page can be seen [here](http://attic.ryantroyford.com/isotope/). Any help is much appreciated. Thank you!

```
<script>
$(function(){

  var $container = $('#container');

  $container.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.brick',

    masonry: {
     columnWidth: 250,
     cornerStampSelector: '.corner-stamp'
    }
  });

  // filter items when filter link is clicked
  $('header a').click(function(){
    var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    $container.isotope({ filter: selector });
    return false;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you're missing the modified methods that can be found in the demo's page source. View source, and copy and paste them along with your isotope code. They look like

```
$.Isotope.prototype._masonryResizeChanged = function() {
  return true;
};

$.Isotope.prototype._masonryReset = function() {
  // mod code...
};
```

Demo: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/custom-layout-modes/masonry-corner-stamp.html

Docs: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/layout-modes.html#modified_layout_modes

---

I just updated the docs, so you didn't have this info quite as apparent before.